# Programming ATMEGA328p via AVR Pocket Programmer

Tags: arduino-uno, avr, avrdude

I have a ATMEGA328p on a breadboard with the following connections to the 2x3 ICSP connector and its connected to AVR Pocket Programmer.

While running AVRDUDE utility, i get the following error,

avrdude -c usbtiny -p m328p

[image]

The controller is powered by the AVR and i have made certain about the pinout. Anyone run into the above error?

Adding more verbose output from the terminal.

[image]

Comment: please do not post pictures of text

Comment: Is the chip wired to receive the correct clock that it is configured for?

Comment: There is no mention of any external clk needed or required.

Comment: Hi, which text to be specific so I can remove that.